# Clearing a Rails Session during Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-store

How do I clear the rails session so I can start with a fresh slate?  I know I could just nullify each of the session variables with `session[:my_var] = nil`, but is there a rake task or something that knows how to restore the session data to its most basic form?

I'm using [Spree](http://demo.spreecommerce.com/) and it stores a few properties in the session that I would like to clear out to see what's going on in the background, such as `order_id`, `order_token`, `user_credentials_id`, etc.

I'm using SQLite3

Comment: I now just use `session.clear` in a before filter for something quick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
rake db:sessions:clear
```

Comment: when I run that I get:  rake aborted!
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: sessions: DELETE FROM sessions.  I've run rake db:migrate and all that already, so everything's in there

Comment: Then you're probably not using the database for your session data. If you're using just cookies you could just clear your cookies in your browser.

Comment: Look at `ActionController::Base.session_store` in `session_store.rb`

Answer (score 7):

Check your session_store in your environment.rb file.
You can use the  "db:sessions:clear" only if it says active_record.  In this case you are dumping your session in db.

Otherwise just clear your browser cookies.