# Unable to end user session in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, bcrypt

I'm building a basic app in Rails, using Bcrypt and has_secure_password for authentication.

I was trying to delete the User, by putting a link in the views and then the basic method in the user controller:

```
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to root_path(@user)
  end
```

The problem is that this seems to delete the user without ending the session first, so now I am trapped in a loop wherein the error message reads: Couldn't find User with 'id'=5, because the user has been deleted.

I have tried to kill the user session in the terminal by using: kill -9 PID, but this did not have the intended effect. It only seemed to be the same as ctrl-c.

I would like to know how I am able to end a user session in the terminal if this should ever happen again, and how I am able to delete a user and the user session at the same time. Thank you

PS. The sessions controller has the following methods as per Bcrypt:

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
   if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to new_comment_path, notice: "Logged in!"
   else
    flash.now.alert = "Email or password is invalid"
    render "new"
   end
  end

 def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged out!"
 end
```

Comment: First you need to signout from the session and then delete the user after that. How are you creating the session? please provide the method.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to included the sessions controller - here it is now

Comment: I think you can destroy your user below or above `session[:user_id] = nil` line.

Comment: you can use ActionController's `reset_session` method on your reset your current session's hash

Answer (score 0):

In your destroy method you can do this:

```
def destroy
  User.find(session[:user_id]).destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged out!"
end
```

Comment: You mean in the sessions controller? Also - I'm still prevented from using the local host right now because the current_user can't be found. Do you know how I can end the current session? Thanks

Comment: You can use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175169/clearing-a-rails-session-during-development). It says you can do it by rails console and enter `rake db:sessions:clear`

Comment: This should be in the users_controller, in sessions_controller it will delete user after every logout :)